# Pass data into FormRequest in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In Laravel 5 how do you pass data into the FormRequest class?

## Background

I am attempting to validate a get variable that comes from a HTML select element.

I am doing this by subclassing FormRequest and adding to the rules array. I would like to build this validation rule dynamically from the list of files to stay DRY.

What is the best way to pass this list into FileFormRequest?

app/Http/Controllers/UploadController.php (please excuse the public property)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Requests\FileFormRequest;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use File;

class UploadController extends Controller
{

    public $files = [];

    public function get(FileFormRequest $request)
    {
        $files_dir = storage_path('app').'/spreadsheets';
        foreach (File::allFiles($files_dir) as $file) {
            $file = $file->getBasename();
            $this->files[$file] = $file;
        }

        return view('main', array(
            'title' => '',
            'file_names' => $this->files,
            'file_name' => '',
            'sheet_name' => '',
            'encoding' => 'UTF-8'
        ));
    }

}
```

app/Http/Requests/FileFormRequest.php

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Response;

class FileFormRequest extends FormRequest
{

    public function rules()
    {
        // What goes here in place of the empty array?
        $files = implode(',', []);

        return [
            'file_name' => 'sometimes|required|in:'.$files,
        ];

    }

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I solved this by

- moving the upload file listing functionality into a utility interface and class
- using a service provider to expose an instance of the utility class as a service
- injecting the service into both the Controller and FormRequest classes

Code was:

app/Contracts/Utilities/UploadFilesContract.php - create the interface

```
<?php

namespace App\Contracts\Utilities;

interface UploadFilesContract {

    public function __construct($dir);

    public function getDir();

    public function getFilesBasenames();

}
```

app/Utilities/UploadFiles.php - create the class with the listing functionality

```
<?php

namespace App\Utilities;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use App\Contracts\Utilities\UploadFilesContract;

class UploadFiles implements UploadFilesContract {

    private $dir;
    private $files;

    public function __construct($dir = '')
    {
        $this->dir = storage_path('app').(0 < strlen($dir) ?  '/'.$dir : '');
        $this->files = File::allFiles($this->dir);
    }

    public function getDir()
    {
        return $this->dir;
    }

    public function getFilesBasenames()
    {
        $files = [];
        foreach ($this->files as $file) {
            $file = $file->getBasename();
            $files[$file] = $file;
        }
        return $files;
    }

}
```

app/Providers/UploadFilesServiceProvider.php - bind the interface to an instance of the class

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Utilities\UploadFiles;

class UploadFilesServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $defer = true;

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bindShared('App\Contracts\Utilities\UploadFilesContract', function($app) {
            return new UploadFiles('spreadsheets');
        });
    }

    public function provides()
    {
        return ['App\Utilities\UploadFiles'];
    }
}
```

app/Http/Controllers/UploadController.php - inject the uploaded files interface in the constructor

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Requests\FileFormRequest;
use App\Contracts\Utilities\UploadFilesContract;

class UploadController extends Controller
{

    private $upload_files;

    public function __construct(UploadFilesContract $upload_files) {
        $this->upload_files = $upload_files;
    }

    public function get(FileFormRequest $request)
    {   
        return view('main', array(
            'title' => '',
            'file_names' => $this->upload_files->getFilesBasenames(),
            'file_name' => '',
            'sheet_name' => '',
            'encoding' => 'UTF-8'
        ));
    }

}
```

app/Http/Requests/FileFormRequest.php - inject the uploaded files interface in the constructor

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use App\Contracts\Utilities\UploadFilesContract;

class FileFormRequest extends FormRequest
{
    private $upload_files;

    public function __construct(array $query = array(), array $request = array(), array $attributes = array(), array $cookies = array(), array $files = array(), array $server = array(), $content = null, UploadFilesContract $upload_files)
    {
        parent::__construct($query, $request, $attributes, $cookies, $files, $server, $content);
        $this->upload_files = $upload_files;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        $files = implode(',', $this->upload_files->getFilesBasenames());

        $rules = [
            'file_name' => 'sometimes|required|in:'.$files,
        ];

        return $rules;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

config/app.php - register the provider

```
<?php

// ...

'providers' => [

    // ...

    App\Providers\UploadFilesServiceProvider::class,

],

// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
public function rules()
{
    // Get the REQUEST (GET/POST) variable
    $files = app('request')->get('form_field_name');

    return [
        'file_name' => 'sometimes|required|in:'.$files,
    ];

}
```

If `form_field_name` is not an array then make it an array depending on the value it contains. Also, you may create another `protected` method to get input from request if that requires much code, for example:

```
protected function getRequestInput()
{
    $files = app('request')->get('form_field_name');

    // Process it here and finally return, i.e:
    return $files; // array
}
```

So you are now able to call the method from within `rules` method like this:

```
$files = $this->getRequestInput();
```

Comment: If I understand correctly this would validate `files` against data passed via `form_field_name`. Unfortunately `form_field_name` is a request var and could be modified by the user negating the validation. Therefore I don't think this is a solution. Something similar using the session might work, but feels very hacky.